# Enable restrictions on Guest user

Tags: macos, mail.app, parental-controls, guest-account

Our employees are logging into our shared computer using Guest user.

At some point somebody will click on an email address and Mail.app will open. If they put in their Gmail credentials, then it will download GBs of mail onto the computer. This will be deleted later, which is cool, but this whole process can be avoided.

How do I restrict Mail.app from opening in Guest user?

Also, it would be nice if I can restrict access to Facebook and other such websites that we don't want employees to browse.

Answer (score 3):

Under System Preferences → Users & Groups → Guest User after you have allowed Guest user login by checking **Allow guests to log in to this computer**, you'll get an option to **Enable parental controls**.

[image]

Clicking on **Open Parental Controls...** button will present the setting for the configurations you are looking for. You can limit Guest user access to select apps, allow access to only a select websites and set other restrictions.

[image]

[image]